# How to factor numbers that are the product of two primes if number is too big

Tags: python, rsa

after sitting here for a while and still dont know how to find the p and q in rsa. If the number is too big, it needs too much time. Is there an efficient way to calculate p and q?

Suppose N = 140685674613168
I sqrt it and just need to find two primes which get n = p * q.

```
   def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

This function gets me a list of possible prime integers which I can multiply

```
   t = primes(sqrtN)
   for i in range(len(t),0,-1):
        sqrtN = sqrtN - 1 
        if(sqrtN in t):
            p = t[i]
            q = sqrtN
            if((p*q) == N):
             print("found")  
             break
```

The problem here is, it takes too much time.

Is there a better way to find p and q in really short time? I already google it but none of them works fine with this big number.

Comment: Good luck with factoring 2048 bit N.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't only use a hell of time it will probably also consume a lot of RAM, as you have to create an array with sqrt(N) elements.
Perhaps creating this list and punching out all the products of primes found so far is even slower than just trying 2 and all odd numbers >= 3.

However this will not be fast for big numbers.

Another note:

I assume you made a typo with the number in your example. 140685674613168 is an even number, so the first prime would be 2 and the other prime would be N/2 which would be 70342837306584 if N were really the product of two primes.

Also your code doesn't seem to perform the right tests:

You might try following

```
N = 140685674613168

sqrt = int(N ** 0.5) + 1

if N % 2 == 0:
        print("%d = %d * %d" % (N, 2, N/2))
for v in range(3,sqrt,2):
    if N % v == 0:
        print("%d = %d * %d" % (N, v, N/v))
```

The output will show you however that the given number is not a product of two prime numbers:

```
140685674613168 = 2 * 70342837306584
140685674613168 = 3 * 46895224871056
140685674613168 = 5477 * 25686630384
140685674613168 = 6113 * 23014178736
140685674613168 = 16431 * 8562210128
140685674613168 = 18339 * 7671392912
140685674613168 = 87541 * 1607083248
140685674613168 = 262623 * 535694416
```

Above example executes in < than 2 seconds.

Will need at least sqrt(k) times longer if your N is k times bigger than above N.

Not sure if that will be fast enough for what you try to do

If you expect the prime numbers to be big and you know it's really only the product of two primes you could write:

```
sqrt = int(N ** 0.5) + 1

for v in range(sqrt,3,-2):
    if N % v == 0:
        print("%d = %d * %d" % (N, v, N/v))
        break
```

Comment: if you could factor a product of huge prime numbers really fast, then most crypto algorithms would be dead.

There are some algorithmic tricks to accelerate but they all have their limits and if numbers are big enough you won't be able to determine the two primes within a reasonable amount of time.

Python and normal PC's are not the best means for such tasks.